# Как вызвать функцию после отрисовки ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Здравствуйте.
Пишу одностраничное приложение на angularjs, где по клику по ссылке с помощью ajax получаю данные с сервера. Полученные данные выводятся с помощью ng-repeat. Проблема в том, что я использую скрипты для подсветки кода в html и для того, чтобы эта подсветка появилась, необходимо вызвать функцию, которая и обновляет эти стили.

Например, у меня есть `<pre class="java">code</pre>` После полной загрузки страницы вызывается `$("pre.java").snippet("java")`, но если попробовать вызвать ее после получения ответа по ajax, то она вызывается именно после получения, а не отрисовки на странице. 
Моя директива:

```
app.directive("file", function() {
return {
  restrict : "E",
  scope : true,
  controller : function($scope, $element) {
  $scope.fileName = $scope.file.fileName;
  $scope.fileContent = $scope.file.content;
  },

  link : function(scope, el, attr) {
  scope.fileName = scope.fileName;
  scope.fileContent = scope.fileContent;
  },
  template : 
  "<h3 class='title'>name: {{fileName}}</h3><pre class=\"java\">content: {{fileContent}}</pre>"
    }
});
```

Пробовал вызывать по условию `$last`. Функция отрабатывает, добавляет свои классы в блоку`<pre>`, но после этого не происходит замена `fileContent`. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно следующее должно Вам помочь:

**Директива:**

```
 app.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
    <div>{{item.name}}}<div>
</div>
```

Если необходимо получить доступ к событию из **контроллера:**

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    //...
});
```

Comment: Вы наверное перепутали названия, ведь куда более понятней назвать директиву ng, а событие on. И не затруднит ли Вас на человеческом языке объяснить строчку on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished".

Comment: @shatal называйте как удобно по чтению, пример просто для понимания логики) `on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished"` - как завершается рендер ngRepeat - запускаем нужное нам событие.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш способ помог. Еще подсказали  $scope.$$postDigest, который так же помог, но он относится ко внутреннему API и его лучше не использовать.