# AngularJS В разных директивах разное поведение element.children()

Tags: angularjs

Коллеги, в директиве пытаюсь получить потомков. Вопрос в том что, если потомки родителя добавлены через `ng-repeat`, то `element.children()` возвращает пустой массив.

Но если запрашивать через `setTimeout()` я добиваюсь желаемого результата

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.myExample = ['Example-1', 'Example-2', 'Example-3', 'Example-4', 'Example-5'];
       setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("TCL: element", element.children());
      },0)
      
    }
  }
});

app.directive('rootElement', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "ECA",
    //templateUrl: './pages/page-main/index.html',
    template: '<header>header</header><main>main</main><footer>footer</footer>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      console.log("rootElement", element.children());
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example" ng-repeat="example in myExample" ng-click="active = !active" ng-class="active ? '' : 'li-example-active'"><span>{{example}}</span></li>
</menu>
<hr/>
  <root-element></root-element>
<html>
```

После подсказки `@Дмытрык` оказалось, что я наступил на те же грабли. Была такая же почти проблема, но без `Angularjs`.

Вопрос - Верное ли решение использовать `setTimeout()` или есть более изящное и верное решение?

Comment: они не успевают отрисоваться. Выведи лог через setTimeout

Comment: @Дмытрык, ты думаешь те же грабли?

Comment: я не понял о чем ты

Comment: @Дмытрык, мы с тобой такое уже обсуждали как я помню... Да ты оказался прав.... Изменю вопрос

Comment: В ангуляре, по идее, должен быть какой-нибудь встроенный метод/хук, по которому можно определить конец отрисовки DOM. Во Vue это `mounted` и `nextTick`

Comment: @Дмытрык, благодарю.... Не видел ничего такого...

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks - как мне кажется это `ngAfterViewInit()` .  По хорошему, надо каждый из этих хуков прологгировать и четко понимать, когда какой срабатывает

Comment: @Дмытрык, это ссылка на документацию по `angularjs 2 и выше`,  если я верно понял,  у этих версий существенные различия...  Если ошибаюсь, надеюсь меня поправят знающие люди...

Comment: Ты продолжаешь делать не то и не так :)

Comment: @Grundy, Ну подскажи что именно `***НЕ ТАК И НЕ ТО***` и как надо сделать чтобы было `***ТАК и ТО***`

Comment: не надо лезть в `element` в большинстве случаев.

Comment: `ng-repeat` не бросает никаких событий что он закончил `render`, поэтому то, без дополнительных манипулция точно этого отследить не получится. `setTimeout` - в текущем виде может работать не в каждом случае. Скорее всего, как и в предыдущей задаче - ничего этого не нужно.

Comment: @Grundy, уже изучаю твой ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать дополнительную директиву, которая инициирует событие, если элемент `ng-repeat` последний. 
Или можно сразу в этой директиве нужный функционал прописать.

P.S. По мотивам [Как вызвать функцию после отрисовки ng-repeat?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434559/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-ng-repeat)

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
         pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            scope.myExample = [
              'Example-1',
              'Example-2',
              'Example-3',
              'Example-4',
              'Example-5'
            ];
         },
         post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
           scope.$on('NG_REPEAT_FINISHED', () => {
             console.log(iElement.children());
           })
         }
      }
    }
  }
});

app.directive('rootElement', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "ECA",
    //templateUrl: './pages/page-main/index.html',
    template: '<header>header</header><main>main</main><footer>footer</footer>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      console.log("rootElement", element.children());
    }
  }
});

app.directive('onFinished', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope) {
      if (scope.$last) {
        scope.$emit('NG_REPEAT_FINISHED')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<menu class="example">
  <li 
    class="li-example" 
    ng-repeat="example in myExample" 
    ng-click="active = !active" 
    ng-class="active ? '' : 'li-example-active'"
    on-finished
   >
    <span>{{example}}</span>
   </li>
</menu>
<hr/>
<root-element></root-element>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```